# PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER vs Splint

Tags: c, pthreads, conditional-statements, mutex, splint

I have the following code

```
static pthread_mutex_t watchdogMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_cond_t watchdogCond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
```

and I get the following errors/warnings when using Splint

> Static watchdogCond._*data.*_mutex initialized to null
>                             value: watchdogCond._*data.*_mutex = (void *)0
>     A reference with no null annotation is assigned or initialized to NULL.  Use
>     /*@null@*/ to declare the reference as a possibly null pointer. (Use
>     -nullassign to inhibit warning)

What is the issue with this and is it a real danger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `pthread_mutex_t` is an opaque **pointer** (you could track the `typedef` down to find out). In Splint, **pointers are not-nullable** by default. If you want to have a nullable pointer, you must declare it with the semantic annotation `/*@null@*/`, for example:

```
char * ptr1;
/*@null@*/ char * ptr2;

ptr1 = NULL; /* warning: implicitly not-nullable pointer */
ptr2 = NULL; /* OK: explicitly nullable pointer */
```

According to [the manual](http://www.splint.org/manual/html/sec2.html), there are 3 options regarding *null state*:

- `null` Possibly null pointer.
- `notnull` Non-null pointer.
- `relnull` Relax null checking.  No errors when NULL is assigned to it, or when it is used as a non-null pointer.

The **advantage** of using not-nullable pointers is that you don't need to check them every time you get one of them. For example, you could annotate a function parameter as `/*@notnull@*/` and then you are not *required* to check `if(pointer == NULL)` before you dereference it. This reduces checking and simplifies your code.

The ***danger*** of ignoring these warnings is that, if you are telling Splint that a specific pointer can't possibly be null and later on you try to assign `NULL` to it, this null pointer could end up being derefered and the program could crash.

In my opinion, your actual issue is Splint's policy, which considers all pointers implicitly not-nullable. This forces you to annotate all your *possibly null* pointers.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like splint has an issue with explicit initialization of pointers as null., and wants some kind of override-annotation comment to disable the warning. I would simply follow its advice and use the `-nullassign` option to disable this warning. There is nothing bad or harmful about what your code is doing or the way the implementation has defined the initializer macros. It's just splint having irrational fears.

Comment: Thanks. Splint says something about it cannot go on checking the source, after this error I mentioned above.

Comment: Use the `-nullassign` option to turn off this check.